# Invalid numbers of args (TypeError), though exact args given

Tags: python, oop, binary-search-tree

I am trying to create a Binary Search Tree, but it gives me a `TypeError`. How can I pass the second argument (`node`) to `insert()` as the object itself, since the first argument (`self`) is always the instance of `BSTNode`.

```
# Binary Search Tree
# Create a BST and insert elements and print Inorder traversal


class BSTNode(object):
    def __init__(self, key, left=None, right=None):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.key = key

    @property
    def insert(self, node, key):
        if node is None:
            return BSTNode(key)
        elif key < node.key:
            node.left = insert(node.left, key)
        elif key > node.key:
            node.right = insert(node.right, key)
        return node

    @property
    def inorder(root):
        if root:
            inorder(root.left)
            print(root.key)
            inorder(root.right)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bst = BSTNode(50)
    bst.insert(bst, 30)
    bst.insert(bst, 20)
    bst.insert(bst, 40)
    bst.insert(bst, 70)
    bst.insert(bst, 60)
    bst.insert(bst, 80)

    inorder(root)
```

Irrespective of how many arguments I pass to the `insert()`, the above code gives the same Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bst.py", line 31, in <module>
    bst.insert(root, 30)
TypeError: insert() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: What is it, exactly, that you think `@property` does? You are not using it correctly at all.

Comment: Just remove the `@property` decorator. A property is a function declared as a getter, it takes a single argument: `self` and returns the value of the property. The advantage is being able to call `val = obj.prop` instead of `val = obj.prop()`, thus masking the fact that the property is computed instead of a fixed value.

Comment: On top of the incorrect `@property` usage, method calls in python require the `self` prefix. Use `self.insert()` and `self.inorder()`.

Comment: Also last row `inorder(root)` change on `bst.inorder(root)` or create function `inorder()` not in class, and define `root`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't create `@property` for the `insert()` function here (neither for the `inorder()` in this case).

Properties should be used to manage the attributes of a class with getters setters and deleters. The `getter` (which you create with the `@property` decoration and invoke when accesing a property via `bst.insert`) must take a *single* argument `self`. Then, it (normally) returns the attribute it is assigned to.

Instead, use it like a plain `method` and add elements without decorating it, note how I have added `self` to your `insert()` calls:

```
 def insert(self, node, key):
    if node is None:
        return BSTNode(key)
    elif key < node.key:
        node.left = self.insert(node.left, key)
    elif key > node.key:
        node.right = self.insert(node.right, key)
    return node
```

Now your insertions work just fine and return the new node objects:

```
bst.insert(root, 30)
# returns <__main__.BSTNode at 0x7fd9f74a8668>
```

---

The reason this is happening is because the (`__get__`) function for a property internally calls the function (`insert`) you decorated as a getter but with a single argument `insert(instanceOfClass)`.

Because you have defined your function `insert()` with more than one arguments, when this call is made you'll get a nice little `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

@rohit varshney

Reason: Property decorator has 3input args(fget,fset,fdel), doc string.

Property decorator usage is inapproriate here and hence the error.

Fix: Please remove the @property above insert def.

Tutorial on decorators:
https://dzone.com/articles/python-201-decorators